# How do you determine (WinForms) control type in UITestControl?

Tags: winforms, coded-ui-tests

I'm trying to make custom properties for controls available in Coded UI Tests and every example I've found is totally useless.

For instance: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh552522.aspx

```
public override int GetControlSupportLevel(UITestControl uiTestControl)
{
    // For MSAA, check the control type
    if (string.Equals(uiTestControl.TechnologyName, "MSAA",
    StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) &&
    (uiTestControl.ControlType == "Chart"||uiTestControl.ControlType == "Text"))
    {
        return (int)ControlSupport.ControlSpecificSupport;
    }

    // This is not my control, so return NoSupport
    return (int)ControlSupport.NoSupport;
}

// Get the property value by parsing the accessible description
public override object GetPropertyValue(UITestControl uiTestControl, string propertyName)
{
    if (String.Equals(propertyName, "State", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
    {
        object[] native = uiTestControl.NativeElement as object[];
        IAccessible acc = native[0] as IAccessible;

        string[] descriptionTokens = acc.accDescription.Split(new char[] { ';' });
        return descriptionTokens[1];
    }

    // this is not my control
    throw new NotSupportedException();
}
```

This code is entirely worthless if you have 2 different controls that are "Text" controls - there is no way to determine which type of text control it is. The "ControlType" property is very misleading because it does not return the Type of the control as its name suggests. It's more like a control category. How can you determine what the control actually is?

Comment: Have you looked at GetProperty: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd465184(v=vs.100).aspx

Comment: Why are you linking that?

Comment: @Nick Just to clarify. If control is <Div> you want to get 'Div' and if control is <input type='text'> you want to get 'text'. Is that correct?

Comment: Yeah, sort of. I'm using windows forms controls, though. So if I have a "TextEdit" control and an "IntegerEdit" control I want to to know which one it is instead of the generic "Edit" that UITestControl.ControlType would return.

Answer (score 1):

You can use something like this. Hope this helps.

```
string controlType = control.GetProperty(XamlControl.PropertyNames.ControlType).ToString();
```

Comment: I guess I should add this question is about Windows forms controls not wpf/silverlight xaml controls

Comment: Absolutely right. The sample is based on XAML controls and you can modify it based on the control type.

Comment: How could I possibly modify it based on the control type if I have no idea what the control type is? That is what I am trying to find.